# SQL/Oracle IN clause - how to use values from another table column as a list

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the query like this:

```
WITH table1 as (
   SELECT ...
   ),
   
    table2 as (
     ...
     where ID in table1.ID
```

so I want to use the values from `table1` "ID" column as a list to filter the values in `table2`. Unfortunately, using   `where ID in table1.ID` doesnt work. How can I do that?

Comment: [**IN Condition**](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/img_text/in_condition.html): `( expr [, expr ]... ) in (subquery)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use proper syntax:

```
WITH 
table1 as 
  (
   SELECT ...
  ),   
table2 as 
  (
   SELECT ...
   FROM ...
   WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM table1)     --> this
  )
```

---

On the other hand, consider joining tables:

```
WITH 
table1 as 
  (
   SELECT ...
  ),   
table2 as 
  (
   SELECT ...
   FROM some_table a JOIN table1 t1 ON t1.id = a.id  --> this
   ...
  )
```

Note what @MT0 commented; if there's possibility of duplicate IDs, use the 1st option or - possibly - `select DISTINCT ...`

Comment: Joining tables is not the same. If table1 has duplicate id values then INNER JOIN will generate duplicate rows whereas using IN will not generate duplicates.

Comment: It's better to use appropriate operation for the requirement: to test if a value is in a list `in` is very clear and adds no issues (like duplicate column names in case of `select *` or duplicate rows as commented above). It also nay easily be negated (keeping in mind `null` issues). Another possible benefit is an ability to [evaluate subquery](https://tanelpoder.com/2009/01/23/multipart-cursor-subexecution-and-precompute_subquery-hint/) in a child cursor and pass literal values to the filter.

Comment: I agree with you, guys, thank you for your comments!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `inner join` :

```
WITH table1 as (
   SELECT ...
   ),
table2 as (
    select ...
    from ...
    inner join yourtable t on t.id = table1.id
)
select *
from table2
```

Comment: This is not the same. If `table1` has duplicate `id` values then `INNER JOIN` will generate duplicate rows whereas using `IN` will not generate duplicates.